# ¿Cómo restar a dos entradas distintas un valor variable?

Tags: sqlite

supongamos que tengo una tabla de productos con la siguiente estructura:

```
descripcionProducto  stockProducto  fechaVencimientoProducto
------------------------------------------------------------
producto1            5              05/10/19
producto1            5              10/10/19
producto2            3              07/10/19
```

Y supongamos que quiero dar de baja 6 ítems del producto 1, dando de baja (es decir poner en 0 el stock) primero el que tiene la fecha de vencimiento más próxima y luego el que le siga.

Lo que he probado es lo siguiente, pero me resta en todas las columnas 6 ítems dejando en negativo todos los stocks, pero no sé cómo subtraer un total de 6 a la columna.

```
UPDATE stock SET stockProducto = stockProducto - 6 WHERE stockProducto > 0 AND descripcionProducto = "producto1";
```

Comment: Inténtalo luego pregunta...

Comment: no tengo ni idea para dónde salir disparando, lo que he probado me deja números negativos (cosa que no es factible) o me resta en ambos el valor pero no me resta primero 5 y luego 1 en el otro,  y si tengo más de 2 entradas que tienen que ser "tocadas" me rompe un poco la lógica

Comment: Pon el código que has probado y a partir de allí seguro que llegamos a la solución

Answer (score 2, accepted):

la solución que desarrollé involucra triggers. Cuando detecta que hay un update en la tabla y si el valor de stock de algún producto queda por debajo de 0, entonces busca la siguiente entrada que tenga un stock mayor a 0 (y que además tenga la fecha de vencimiento más próxima) y le resta el valor negativo de la entrada anterior, luego, para evitar tener un stock negativo actualizo el valor para que quede en 0. Lo bueno es que si el nuevo update genera un valor de stock negativo, por lo que pude probar, el trigger se dispara nuevamente y es recursivo.

En la tabla de ejemplo habría que agregar el idProducto que sea un autonumérico para poder indentificar cada entrada.

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS stockNegativo
    AFTER UPDATE
    ON stock
    WHEN new.stockProducto < 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE ingresos
        SET stockProducto = stockProducto + new.stockProducto 
        WHERE stockProducto > 0 
            AND idProducto = (SELECT idProducto FROM stock 
                WHERE stockProducto > 0 
                    AND descripcion = old.descripcion 
                    ORDER BY fechaVencimientoProducto LIMIT 1);
    UPDATE stock
        SET stockProducto = 0 
        WHERE stockProducto < 0
            AND idProducto = (SELECT idProducto FROM stock 
                WHERE stockProducto < 0 
                    AND descripcion = old.descripcion 
                    ORDER BY fechaVencimientoProducto LIMIT 1);
END;
```